# What Keras's Resnet expects as an input?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, theano, keras

I'm trying to use Keras's implementation of resnet for a transfer learaning task with a quite different set of images (B&W 16 bit). So what Keras expects as an input? Image with 3 channels and -127-128 range (that's what I assume zero centered 8 bit image)? 0-255? What would happen if I pass something outside this range?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385v1.pdf) provided in Keras documentation you should provide a `224 x 224 RGB [0 - 225]` image. The actual dimension ordering depends on the backend you use in your Keras installation.

The data preparation was performed as in [AlexNet](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks.pdf) so the mean activation was subtracted from each color channel. The mean vector for RGB is `103.939, 116.779, 123.68`.

If your color values would extend `-255, 255` range - it could harm your training because of the magnitude of data unknown for the network. But still - network could adapt to this changes, but it usually makes more time and make training more chaotic.

In case of monochromatic images - a commonly used technique is a repeating the same channel 3 times in order to make dimensions plausible for network architecture.